# Implement null check logic in Mvc View with a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<div class="form-gridcontrol">
    <label>Notes</label>
    @Html.CustomTextArea(m => m.Notes)
</div>
```

In ASP.NET MVC , I have created a custom textarea and inputing/displaying data from the database using a Model.Above is the code where you can see the Notes are getting assigned to  @Html.CustomTextArea.
I have a situation where , I need to display a text "Not Applicable" if there is no value in "m.Notes" 
How I should right the logic in the above code? Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible ways for this. One of the way is that you can populate in the controller action from where it is loaded like:

```
public ActionResult YourActionMethod()
{
     ............
     ............
     if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Notes))
          model.Notes = "Not Applicable";

     return View(model);
}
```

Another way can be to introdcue the backing field on your property and write in it's getter:

```
private String _notes;
public String Notes
{
   get
   {
      return String.IsNullOrEmpty(_notes) ? "Not Applicable" : _notes;
   }
   set
   {
      _notes = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@if (Model.Notes != null)
  {
      @Html.CustomTextArea(m => m.Notes)
  }
else
  {
    @Html.CustomTextArea( m => m.Notes, new { @Value = "Not Applicable"})
  }
```

edit:this is not working with textarea

```
else
{
  @Html.CustomTextArea(m => m.Notes, new {id="mytextarea"})
  <script>
     $("#mytextarea").text("Not Applicable")
  </script>
}
```

I got a trick for you :)